# Finding the minimum value in a nested dictionary & assigned it to the key [python]

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I'm stuck at some point on how to achieve to get which key has got the minimum pb value in the nested dict below.

```
a = {1230: {'name': 'Jack', 'age': 13, 'pb': 9.3, 'run': 10}, 1241: {'name': 'Sarah', 'age': 6, 'pb': 15.39, 'run': 21}, 1252: {'name': 'Eric', 'age': 6, 'pb': 16.41, 'run': 21}}
```

I applied the logic of getting all pb and assigned them to a new list using tuple:

```
reg = []
for i in a.keys():
   b = ( a[reg], a[reg]['pb'] )
```

Then using the min function to determine which key has the minimum value.

```
print(min(b, key=b.get))
```

Then I'm getting an error saying "TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'"

Any idea as to why I am getting this error because I'm changing the list to a tuple already then applying the min function.

Thank you all in advance for your help.

Comment: The second snippet makes little sense. What did you think `a[reg]` means?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
a = {1230: {'name': 'Jack', 'age': 13, 'pb': 9.3, 'run': 10}, 1241: {'name': 'Sarah', 'age': 6, 'pb': 15.39, 'run': 21},
     1252: {'name': 'Eric', 'age': 6, 'pb': 16.41, 'run': 21}}

key = min(a, key=lambda x: a[x]['pb'])

print(key)
```

**Output**

```
1230
```